# How to make a setInterval wait until another one finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

How, when I click "one" link, make the second counter wait until the first one finishes and then count up to 14 (as instructed on line 155)?

https://jsfiddle.net/c4khk69f/27/

The function responsible for "one" link is function progressSim() on line 43.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

        jQuery('.canvasmotherwrap').hide();
        jQuery('.canvasmotherwrap').fadeIn();     


        al = 0;
        al2 = 0;    

  window.clearInterval(sim1_1);
  window.clearInterval(sim1_2); 
  window.clearInterval(sim2);       

  var storedata = $(this).attr('data');

  console.log(storedata)
  window[storedata]();
});
var sim1_1;
var sim1_2;
var sim2;   


window.one = function() {

  sim1_1 = setInterval(progressSim, 10);
  sim1_2 = setInterval(progressSim, 1000);  
}


window.two = function() {

  sim2 = setInterval(progressSim2, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are after, but I think you want two counters and when the "first" one has finished then the second should start and count to "14".

I hope this helps:

```js
function doWork(targetDiv, startTime, countTo, onDone) {
    var ticker = setInterval(function(){
        diff = (((Date.now() - startTime) / 500) | 0);
        targetDiv.innerText = diff;
        if(diff < countTo){ return; }

        clearInterval(ticker);
        if(typeof(onDone) === 'function') { onDone(); }
    }, 100);

}

var divFoo = document.getElementById("foo");
var divBar = document.getElementById("bar");

// your on "click"
doWork(divFoo, Date.now(), 5, function(){
    doWork(divBar, Date.now(), 14);
});
```

```html
<table><tr>
    <td><div id="foo">0</div></td>
    <td><div id="bar">0</div></td>
</table>
```